# Is Drop Wizard 1.3.7 compatible with Jersey 2.29.1?

Tags: dropwizard

My project needs to upgrade to the latest Jersey version without upgrading drop wizard, currently using 1.3.7.

Comment: Take a look at the migration guide of Dropwizard: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/wiki/Upgrade-guide-1.3.x-to-2.0.x Especially the Jersey part: https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/wiki/Upgrade-guide-1.3.x-to-2.0.x#jersey 2.29 seems to have subtle internal changes. Which means that you will have to work around them, which most probably means reimplementing the changes in Dropwizard 2.x.